# Is there a script to measure face width to height ratio?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, experimental-psychology, evolutionary-psychology, aesthetics

I´d be interested whether you know a script or anything automated to measure the face width to height ratio of a set of pictures depicting faces.

Otherwise, your experience how to do that efficiently or a list of tools to do so easily is highly appreciated as well.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has nothing to do with CogSci. Perhaps Bio.SE is a better choice, but poorly researched questions tend to get closed quickly there. If you could share your efforts in doing this it would be an acceptable question there.

Comment: Hi Florian, if you could explain how measuring the size of one's head may be of use to cognitive science, perhaps people are able/willing to answer your question. In other words, what is the relevance of your question?